# Why does my Travis CI test fail while my local tests pass due to swapped latlng and lnglat data in the Travis test database?

Tags: python, postgis, travis-ci, postgresql-14

I have encountered a perplexing issue with my continuous integration setup using Travis CI. When running my tests locally, everything works perfectly fine and all tests pass without any issues. However, when I push my code to Travis CI for automated testing, a specific set of tests fail consistently.

The root cause of the problem seems to be related to the way location data is stored and retrieved from the test database. In my code, I expect the location data to be in the format of latlng (latitude, longitude), which is how it is stored in the database when I run tests locally. However, on Travis CI, it appears that the location data is being retrieved in the format of lnglat (longitude, latitude), causing assertions to fail due to this unexpected data format.

I've verified that the test database setup and data generation are consistent between my local environment and Travis CI, so there shouldn't be any differences in the data itself. It seems like there might be an environmental or configuration difference causing this issue.

Here are some additional details that might help diagnose the problem:

I'm using the same database configuration locally and on Travis CI.(postgresql-14-postgis-3, python 3.8)
I've double-checked the database migrations and seed data to ensure consistency.
My test suite runs the same test cases both locally and on Travis CI.
I'm not explicitly modifying the location data format in my test cases.
I'm looking for guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue further and understand why the data format for location data is swapping between latlng and lnglat on Travis CI but not locally. Any insights or suggestions on where to look or what might be causing this behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!